# Remix testing timeout with JavaScript VM when calling a large array

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, javascript-vm

I'm trying to test a contract getter method that returns a large array. I am using Remix and deploying using JavaScript VM. My contract deploys alright, but trying to call the `getArray()` method causes Remix to freeze and show a timeout page.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;    
contract myContract{
        bytes32[7500] public array;
        function getArray() public view returns(bytes32[7500]){
            return array;
        }
}
```

I also have a [similar problem when testing the web3 library in Mocha with ganache-cli provider](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51931/mocha-timeout-not-resolving-promise-of-large-array-from-method-mymethod-call).

However, When I deploy using Injected Web3 to Rinkeby, Remix returns the large array just fine. Is this timeout some sort of limitation of the JS VM? Thanks.