# Mocha timeout, not resolving promise of large array from method.mymethod.call()

Tags: web3js, arrays, ganache, mocha

I'm trying to test a contract getter method that returns a large array. I am testing using the web3 library in Mocha with ganache-cli provider. My contract deploys alright, but trying to call the `getArray()` test doesn't pass.

Contract:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.24;    
    contract myContract{
            bytes32[7500] public array;
            function getArray() public view returns(bytes32[7500]){
                return array;
            }
    }
```

Test:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const compiledContract = require('../ethereum/build/myContract.json');

let accounts;
let mycontract;

beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    mycontract = await new web3.eth.Contract(
        JSON.parse(compiledContract.interface))
        .deploy({data: compiledContract.bytecode})
        .send({from: accounts[0], gas:'6000000'});

});

describe('ourPlace', () => {
    it('allows manager to retrieve array', async (done) =>{

            const array = await mycontract.methods.getArray().call({from: accounts[0], gas:'6000000'});
            const length = array.length;
            console.log(length);
            assert.equal(7500, length);

        }).timeout(15000);
});
```

I first tested with 'done' and '.timeout'. The log reports a proper length of 7500 despite the Promise not resolving. The error reads:

> Error: Timeout of 15000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

I have had a somewhat [similar issue with Remix's Javascript VM](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51930/remix-testing-timeout-with-javascript-vm-when-calling-a-large-array). But, when I deploy on Remix using Injected Web3 to Rinkeby, Remix returns the large array just fine. This makes sense because it's just a call.  How do I resolve this promise? I would like to be able to run the tests properly. Thanks.

Edit: Full test code. Dependencies: "fs-extra": "^6.0.1","ganache-cli":"^6.1.3","mocha": "^5.2.0","solc": "^0.4.24","web3": "^1.0.0-beta.34"

Comment: Something doesn't quite make sense here. Are you using Truffle for testing (i.e., `truffle test`)? If yes, then your code seems to be using `web3 v1.0`, while Truffle currently works with `web3 v0.18.4`. The syntax in these two versions is completely different, so I am left to assume that you're not using Truffle for testing. How else are you testing it? Directly with node?

Comment: In any case, I've changed your code to use the syntax of `web3 v0.18.4`, and then tested it with Truffle. It works fine. The `done` parameter is no longer necessary, but Truffle (or Mocha) doesn't seem to mind it being passed to the `it`. Perhaps this is no longer the case with `web3 v1.0`, so try to remove it in your code.

Comment: Hi @goodvibration thanks for the comment. That's a rookie mistake on my part not putting version numbers. I think I am testing directly with node then based on your comments and definitely web3 v1.0 as I really don't know much about promises and callbacks. Will edit question with more info.